# Create a floated RSS image in a HTML email

Tags: html-email

I've been coding HTML Emails for a while.  I'm well aware that using `align="left"` is a good way to float an image because `float` won't work.

A problem arises when you need to use it in an RSS based email as the feed pulls in the image and you have no way to add `align="left"` to the image.  So my initial thought was to put the image into a table.  I didn't want to use two columns because I want the text to wrap around the image.  So I created a table within a table, and the text was not within a table.

In some instances it wraps, but in Outlook the text doesn't sit next to the image table, it starts at the bottom of it.

Here's my code.

```
      <table border="0" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" style="width:600px;max-width:600px">
    <tr>
      <td class="container-padding content" align="left" style="padding-left:24px;padding-right:24px;padding-bottom:12px;background-color:#ffffff;font-family: Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans';"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="50%" align="left" style="padding-right:15px;">
          <tr>
            <td width="50%" style="width:50%"><a href="*|RSSITEM:URL|*"> *|RSSITEM:IMAGE|* </a></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="title" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans';font-size:24px;font-weight:normal;color:#C33734"><a href="*|RSSITEM:URL|*" style="text-decoration:none;">*|RSSITEM:TITLE|*</a></div>
        <div class="author" style="padding-top:2px;padding-bottom:5px;font-size:18px;color:#5584C4"> *|RSSITEM:AUTHOR|* </div>
        <div class="date" style="padding-top:2px;padding-bottom:5px;font-size:16px;color:#86BE3C;"> *|RSSITEM:DATE|* </div>
        <br />
        <div class="body-text" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans';font-size:14px;line-height:20px;text-align:left;color:#333333;padding-bottom:8px;padding-top:8px;">*|RSSITEM:CONTENT|* </div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach works.  When I run it through Email On Acid I get these results.  Outlook appears to be working with the code below.
[image: Desktop Email Client results]

```
 <table border="0" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" style="width:600px;max-width:600px">
    <tr>
      <td class="container-padding content" align="left" style="padding-left:24px;padding-right:24px;padding-bottom:12px;background-color:#ffffff;font-family: Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans';">
       <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="50%" align="left" style="padding-right:15px;">
          <tr>
            <td width="50%" style="width:50%"><a href="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg"> <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg" width="350" height="100" alt=""> </a></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="title" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans';font-size:24px;font-weight:normal;color:#C33734"><a href="*|RSSITEM:URL|*" style="text-decoration:none;">Lorem ipsum Duis dolor sit.</a></div>
        <div class="author" style="padding-top:2px;padding-bottom:5px;font-size:18px;color:#5584C4"> Lorem ipsum Officia aliquip quis. </div>
        <div class="date" style="padding-top:2px;padding-bottom:5px;font-size:16px;color:#86BE3C;"> 5/31/2015 </div>
        <br />
        <div class="body-text" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans';font-size:14px;line-height:20px;text-align:left;color:#333333;padding-bottom:8px;padding-top:8px;">Lorem ipsum Ex incididunt cillum enim sed enim consectetur culpa incididunt enim ut ut tempor mollit adipisicing irure anim in occaecat aute officia magna dolor do tempor occaecat et aliqua. </div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Strange, when I run it through email on acid my code doesn't work, nor when I receive it in my inbox on Outlook.  Perhaps the RSS feed is causing an issue somehow?  Any ideas on that one?

Comment: Are you getting the content you expect from the RSS?  No additional code or text, etc.

Comment: I believe the problem is caused by the fact RSS images add in their own stuff such as size etc.  The solution is to resolve the problem at the RSS end of the stick.